# Linq From Multiple Lists using SelectMany

Tags: linq-to-objects

I am able to return a grouped list of items from my collection using the following code:

```
var items = collection.SelectMany(myObj => myObj.ToNames)
    .GroupBy(name => name)
    .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

The above code gives me a nice list of unique names and the number of times they were found in the collection.  I now have a need to do the same thing, but group the Names from two seperate collections found in the same MyObj.  I now want to group myObj.ToNames and myObj.FromNames in the same manner - along with getting the overall unique count for each unique name found (no matter which collection it was found in).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Union:

```
var items = collection.SelectMany(myObj => myObj.ToNames.Union(myObj.FromNames))
    .GroupBy(name => name)
    .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Concat:

```
var items = collection.SelectMany(myObj => myObj.ToNames.Concat(myObj.FromNames))
    .GroupBy(name => name)
    .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Comment: The difference being that concat will return duplicates; most likely this is what you want

Comment: You should update your Concat version to reflect the .Concat, but this is exactly what I was looking for.  I need to account for the duplicates in the group by clause, so I assume using Concat will accomplish this?  Thanks!